# Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection. at Protocol.end

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a service with express and after a while I get:
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection. at Protocol.end

My code is as follows:

App.js

```
                var createError = require('http-errors');
            var express = require('express');
            var path = require('path');
            var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
            var logger = require('morgan');
            var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
            var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
            var app = express();
            app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
            app.use(cookieParser());
            app.use(function (req, res, next) {
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,UPDATE,OPTIONS');
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
            next();
            });
            const mysql = require('mysql');
            const connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: '192.0.0.127',
            port: 8080,
            user: 'user',
            password: '',
            database: '',
            insecureAuth: true
            });
            connection.connect(function (err) {
            (err) ? console.log('Error en la conexion') : console.log('Conectado');
            });
            require('./routes/html-routes')(app, connection);
```

AND html-routes.js:

```
            const path = require("path");
            const mysql = require("mysql");
            const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
            const express = require("express");

            module.exports = function(app, connection) {
                router.get("/disponible", function(req, res) {
                    var tipo = req.query.tipo;
                    connection.query("call sp_disponible('" + tipo + "');", function(
                        err,
                        data
                    ) {
                        err ? res.send(err) : res.json({ disponible: data });
                    });
                });

                router.post("/distanciaTorton", function(req, res) {
                    var servicio = req.query.servicio;
                    connection.query(
                        "call sp_distanciaTorton('" + servicio + "');",
                        function(err, data) {
                            err ? res.send(err) : res.json({ distancia: data });
                        }
                    );
                });

                app.use("/tes/api", router);
            };
```

My repository on Github: https://github.com/GabrielaVillaAngeles/BackEndExpress

My backend service throws me the following log:

```
            Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
            at Protocol.end (/var/www/tescobedoBackEnd/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
            at Socket. (/var/www/tescobedoBackEnd/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:97:28)
            at Socket. (/var/www/tescobedoBackEnd/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
            at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
            at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
            at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
            at args.(anonymous function) (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/event-loop-inspector/index.js:138:29)
            at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
            at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
            Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
            at Protocol.end (/var/www/tescobedoBackEnd/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
            at Socket. (/var/www/tescobedoBackEnd/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:97:28)
            at Socket. (/var/www/tescobedoBackEnd/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
            at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
            at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
            at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
            at args.(anonymous function) (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/event-loop-inspector/index.js:138:29)
            at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
            at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
            Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
            at Protocol.end (/var/www/tescobedoBackEnd/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
            at Socket. (/var/www/tescobedoBackEnd/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:97:28)
            at Socket. (/var/www/tescobedoBackEnd/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
            at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
            at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
            at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
            at args.(anonymous function) (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/event-loop-inspector/index.js:138:29)
            at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
            at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either create a connection for each database request or use a connection pool. Using a pool is probably the better way to go.

Replace your createConnection code with something like this:

```
  config =  {
    connectionLimit: 15,
    queueLimit: 10,
    host: "...",
    user: "...",
    password: "..."
  };

  const db = mysql.createPool(config);
  const connection = db.getConnection();

  ...
  ...
  connection.query(..., callback(err, data) {...});
```

Comment: Use `creatPool`, not `createConnection`